# set Entity Reference with VBO and Rules

Tags: rules, entities, views

I migrated my reference module to the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module and now i see we lost all the references to the nodes and since there with so much, i was thinking about doing it with rules and VBO.

We have the following content types that needed to be linked:
Album,
Band

Album has a node reference field that links to a band-type.

The thing is, a band has multiply albums linked to it, now that's where I got stuck, I need to get a list of albums(no issue with views) and then I need to select the band to link them to and then I should change it with rules, to link em back..

I've already looked at a few related questions, but non do exact what i need...

I'd be very happy if somebody could point me into the right direction.

Comment: If you looked at related questions, please link to them and explain why they don't do what you want to do/why the solutions don't work for you.

Comment: I looked at the following links that help me in the right directions: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30767/entity-reference-with-vbo-and-rules and http://nodeone.se/en/creating-multiple-back-links

now, i need to select the band somewhere and link it to the album, or reversen select all albums, link it to one band.. thats the part i don't find..